# Intellij IDEA 2016.3 default properties file encoding doesn't work

Tags: intellij-idea, encoding

I've set the Default encoding for properties files to "ISO-8859-1" in my Intellij IDEA 2016.3, then I create properties files, but the file encoding is still UTF-8:

[image]

Any idea? Or should this be an issue?

Updates:

After changed the project and system default encoding to ISO-8859-1 and then create new properties file, it is still applied with UTF-8 encoding, and I can't manually change the properties file encoding while I do be able to change encoding for other files.

Updates:

I've created an issue on youtrack:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165440

Comment: Did you try unticking "Transparent native to ascii conversion" ? There is some trickery for encoding special characters like `æøå` as `\u01234` in properties files.

Comment: unticking  "Transparent native to ascii conversion" doesn't solve the problem. And I really need that feature. Clearly remember this works before

Answer (score 14):

Today I faced exactly the same problem. I found a workaround to fix the affected properties files:

1. rename the file to txt; make sure the checkbox 'Rename bound resource bundle' is unchecked (e.g. locale-en.properties -> locale_en.txt)
2. go to -> File -> Settings -> File Encodings -> chose the renamed file in the file tree to the right
3. You are now able to chose the new encoding from the drop-down list (e.g. ISO-8859-1)
4. Choose 'OK' and then 'Convert' (confirm also the warning about characters that can't be converted, if a dialog shows up)
5. Rename the file back to it's original name (e.g. locale-en.properties)
6. If the dialog in step 4 showed up, make sure that you fix the characters which were not converted properly (in my case some of the German umlaut showed up as ? and had to be fixed manually)