# Can't edit message bundle files

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.3 (Community Edition)

Open file **messagesBundle_ru_RU.properties**:

[image]

How I can edit this file?

P.S. I converted it to UTF-8, but it not help

[image]

Comment: What file encoding is set for the file? (see bottom right corner of the editor) See if https://stackoverflow.com/a/42368991/12844632 helps

Comment: @EgorKlepikov ISO-8859-1

Comment: @EgorKlepikov I updated post. But it not help